# More Applicative trouble with a vector type enforcing length 2^n

Tags: haskell

Sorry for the botched up first version of the simplified function, I hope that the updated second version below makes more sense. Sorry also for the non-standard notation, but I didn't/don't care much about the auxiliary type Nat and preferred to save some typing for my "scalar vectors" (for my next question I promise to value the sanity of my readers higher, and adapt my code before posting).

---

I'm using the same vector type constrained to have $2^n$ elements as in [my question few hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56184777/11514944):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

data Nat = Z | N Nat
data Vector n t where
  S :: t -> Vector Z t
  V :: Vector n t -> Vector n t -> Vector (N n) t

instance Functor (Vector n) where
  fmap f (S t ) = S (f t)
  fmap f (V t t') = V (fmap f t) (fmap f t')

instance Applicative (Vector Z) where
  pure = S
  S f <*> S a = S (f a)
instance Applicative (Vector n) => Applicative (Vector (N n)) where
  pure a = let a' = pure a in V a' a'
  V f f' <*> V a a' = V (f <*> a) (f' <*> a')

instance (Num t, Applicative (Vector n)) => Num (Vector n t) where
  v + v' = (+) <$> v <*> v'
  v * v' = (*) <$> v <*> v'
  abs = fmap abs
  signum = fmap signum
  fromInteger = pure . fromInteger
  negate = fmap negate
```

Now I failed to implement a quite complex recursive function that I cannot reproduce here, but the essence of my problems can be seen in this much simpler function (that doesn't make much sense, sorry):

```
dummy :: Applicative (Vector n) => Vector n Int -> Vector n Int -> Int
dummy (S a) (S b)       = a + b
dummy (V a a') (V b b') = dummy (a*b) (a'*b')
```

The error message my compiler (ghci, still Haskell Platform 8.0.2-a on Windows 7) gives me is (slightly shortened):

```
• Could not deduce (Applicative (Vector n2))
    arising from a use of ‘dummy’
  from the context: Applicative (Vector n)
    bound by the type signature for:
               dummy :: Applicative (Vector n) =>
                        Vector n Int -> Vector n Int -> Int
    at ...
  or from: n ~ 'N n2
    bound by a pattern with constructor:
               V :: forall t (n :: Nat).
                    Vector n t -> Vector n t -> Vector ('N n) t,
             in an equation for ‘dummy’
    at ...
• In the expression: dummy (a * b) (a' * b')
  In an equation for ‘dummy’:
      dummy (V a a') (V b b') = dummy (a * b) (a' * b')
```

To me it looks similar to the problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331925/applicative-instance-of-a-vector-with-kind-nats).

I tried way around it, by defining separately

```
dummy :: Applicative (Vector Z) => Vector n Int -> Vector n Int -> Int
dummy = ...
```

and

```
dummy :: Applicative (Vector n) => Vector (N n) Int -> Vector (N n) Int -> Int
dummy = ...
```

but then the Compiler complains

```
...: error:
  Duplicate type signatures for ‘dummy’
  at ...
```

Do I have to define a type class with the only function dummy and then make `Vector Z` and (Vector (N n)) instances of it?

```
class Dummy d where
  dummy :: d -> d -> Int
instance Dummy (Vector Z Int) where
  dummy (S a) (S b) = a + b
instance (Applicative (Vector n), Dummy (Vector n Int)) => Dummy (Vector (N n) Int) where
  dummy (V a a') (V b b') = dummy (a*b) (a'*b')
```

The compiler takes it, but is there no better way to do it?

---

I guess dfeuer's answer contains a better solution, but I wasn't able to adapt it to my definition of Nat (yet).

Comment: FYI, type errors are not platform dependent. Just the GHC version will do, and maybe the versions of relevant non-base packages you're using.

Comment: Your `dummy` doesn't use the `Applicative` instance. Does the real function?

Comment: Also: `data Nat = Z | S Nat` is so common that using an `N` constructor instead throws everyone for a loop. You should rename the singleton `Vector` constructor to free up `S`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! One way to do this is to recover an `Applicative` instance just in time, recursing over the spine of the tree when we discover we need it. So:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
withApplicative :: Vector n t -> (Applicative (Vector n) => a) -> a
withApplicative S{} a = a
withApplicative (V v _) a = withApplicative v a
```

Armed with this, we can call for the appropriate instance without putting it in our context:

```
dummy :: Vector n Int -> Vector n Int -> Int
dummy (S a) (S b) = a + b
dummy (V a a') (V b b') = withApplicative a (dummy (a*b) (a'*b'))
```

Since `withApplicative` is linear in the depth of your tree, and we call `withApplicative` once at each depth, this adds a runtime component that is quadratic in the depth of your tree to build up appropriate `Applicative` dictionaries. With some work it should be possible to share the dictionaries across recursive calls to drop the cost to linear in the depth; but since the computation itself is already exponential in the depth, perhaps an extra quadratic cost is small enough already.

**What's going on with `withApplicative`?**

Okay, we've got a `Vector n t` in our hands. Now, we carefully set up `Vector` so that it only accepts `Nat`-kinded values of `n`, and we smart programmers know that a `Nat` is some longish sequence of applications of `N`s to a final `Z`. But the compiler doesn't know that*, it just knows that it has some type `n` of kind `Nat`. Consequently, since it doesn't know it's a bunch of `N`s applied to `Z`, it doesn't know how to build up an `Applicative` instance -- since all the `Applicative` instances for `Vector` demand that the `Nat` argument to `Vector` be visibly either a `Z` or an `N _`. The type variable `n` is neither of these. This is the problem we are setting out to solve.

Or, you can take this alternative description of the problem: even if we tell the compiler that we have an `Applicative` instance for `Vector n`, as soon as we discover that `n ~ N n'` (say, by pattern-matching on the `Vector` and seeing that it's got a `V` constructor at its head), we are back to square one on the recursive call, because we haven't told the compiler that we have an `Applicative` instance for `Vector n'`. So an alternative way of thinking of the solution is that we'd like to have some way of saying that if we've got an `Applicative` instance for `Vector n`, we must have had an `Applicative` instance for all the predecessors of `n` (all the "smaller" `Nat`s).

But wait! We have a trick up our sleeves. We've stored away some information in our `Vector` that, through pattern matching, lets us figure out *exactly* what `Nat` that `n` variable is! Namely: `S _` vectors have got `n ~ Z`, and `V _ _` vectors have got `n ~ N n'` (then we must recurse to figure out what `n'` is). So if we were somehow able to pattern match all the way down to an `S`, we would have simultaneously caused the type-checker to know the value of `n` all the way down to a `Z`. Then it could work its way back up, constructing `Applicative` instances for `Z` and then `N Z` and then `N (N Z)` and so on all the way back up to the value it now knows for `n`.

So this is the plan: if we need an `Applicative` instance to compute a thing, pattern match on applications of `V` all the way down to an `S` to learn how many applications of `N` there are to a `Z`; then use this knowledge to build the instance.

That's the intuition. Let's get to the mechanics.

```
withApplicative :: Vector n t -> (Applicative (Vector n) => a) -> a
```

This type signature says: suppose you need an `Applicative` instance to compute a thing -- specifically, an `a` thing. That is, suppose you've got a computation of type `Applicative (Vector n) => a`. If you *also* have a `Vector n t`, I can pattern match on that `Vector` to learn the value of `n` and build you the `Applicative` instance, so I can give you back an `a` thing that has already used the `Applicative` instance and doesn't need it any more. Compare this type:

```
withFoo :: Foo -> (Foo -> a) -> a
```

"If you have a thing that depends on a `Foo`, and a `Foo`, I can give you the corresponding thing." And this type:

```
withComputedFoo :: Bar -> (Foo -> a) -> a
```

"If you have a thing that depends on a `Foo`, I can cook up a `Foo` to hand it even if you give me a `Bar` instead." (For example, `withComputedFoo` might contain within it a function of type `Bar -> Foo` which it applies to the `Bar` you give it.) And now revisiting our type:

```
withApplicative :: Vector n t -> (Applicative (Vector n) => a) -> a
```

"If you have a thing that depends on an `Applicative (Vector n)` dictionary, if you hand me a `Vector n t` I'll cook up the dictionary for you and give you the corresponding thing."

Alright, but how does it work?

```
withApplicative S{} a = a
```

If you handed me a vector whose constructor is `S`, then I know that `n` was `Z`. So now I've learned that whereas before I had `a :: Applicative (Vector n) => a`, now I have `a :: Applicative (Vector Z) => a`. Since there's an `Applicative (Vector Z)` instance in the global scope, I can just use that, so I can also give this the type `a :: a`. Done with this case!

```
withApplicative (V v _) a = withApplicative v a
```

If you handed me a vector whose constructor is `V` instead, then I know that `n` was actually `N n'` for some `n'` (and crucially, `v :: Vector n' t`). So now whereas before I had `a :: Applicative (Vector n) => a`, now I have `a :: Applicative (Vector (N n')) => a`. Ah! But we have an instance `Applicative (Vector n) => Applicative Vector (N n)` in the global scope, so this constraint can be simplified a little bit to just `a :: Applicative (Vector n') => a`. Since we have a vector of length `n'` lying around -- namely, `v` -- now we can recurse, although notice that the `Nat`-kinded type in the recursive call has changed! Now we are calling `withApplicative` with `v :: Vector n' t` and `a :: Applicative (Vector n') => a`, that is, with `n`'s predecessor, `n'`.

And that's all she wrote! The recursion takes care of building the dictionary for the predecessor, and we use the globally-available instance for building the slightly larger dictionary for `n`, and we're on our way.

* The compiler doesn't know it because it isn't, in fact, true. We're lying to ourselves. But it's close enough to true to be a useful mental model.

**Answer to a previous version of the question follows.**

Your `dummy` compiles just fine for me if I just leave off the `Applicative` constraint:

```
dummy :: Vector n Int -> Vector n Int -> Int
dummy (S a) (S b)       = a + b
dummy (V a a') (V b b') = let c  = dummy a b
                              c' = dummy a' b'
                          in c + c'
```

(Perhaps you need to make your motivating example a little bit more complicated to really capture what's hard about your problem...?)

Comment: Thanks, yes the motivating example is too simple. I hope the updated version doesn't have this problem anymore.

Comment: @JohnPoe I've updated my answer to accommodate the new problem.

Comment: Thanks for your magical solution. I do not have any clue how to interpret the three lines defining withApplicative, but I guess that I'll have to learn still quite a bit of haskell until I'll tackle the task to understand what's going on here. Quadratic cost is OK also for my real use case, but I'll wait anyway few days until I'll accept your solution, hoping for a different solution closer to my current knowledge of haskell.

Comment: @JohnPoe I took a stab at writing a bit more expository text on how the solution works. Now that I've written it I'm not certain whether it will be helpful or cause even more confusion; I invite you to take a stab at reading it and let me know which it was in the end.

Comment: Wonderful explanation! I did not expect that it possible to describe what's going on my level. Instead of finding a solution on my level of understanding, you lifted my understanding up to the level of your solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to rename your constructors for the sake of my sanity.

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Vector n a where
  Leaf :: a -> Vector 'Z a
  Branch :: Vector n a -> Vector n a -> Vector ('S n) a
```

The trouble is in the recursive case. Knowing `Applicative ('S n)` does not give you `Applicative n`; you can use only *superclass* constraints, not *instance* constraints, for this. The reason is that an instance constraint just says how to construct a dictionary; it doesn't say anything about what's in it.

I suspect that what you probably want is a very common folklore mechanism using a "singleton" type.

```
data SNat n where
  SZ :: SNat 'Z
  SS :: SNat n -> SNat ('S n)

class KnownNat n where
  known :: SNat n

instance Known 'Z where
  known = SZ

instance Known n => Known ('S n) where
  known = SS known
```

Now you can write functions that work with `SNat`s, and ones that work implicitly with `KnownNat`.

```
dummy :: KnownNat n => Vector n Int -> Vector n Int -> Int
dummy = dummy' known

dummy' :: SNat n -> Vector n Int -> Vector n Int -> Int
```

Note: if you look at my answer to your previous question, you'll see that only the `pure` method of `Applicative` is size-dependent. So if you don't need `pure`, you can probably yank the constraint altogether.

Comment: All of the information available in an `SNat n` is also available in an `Vector n a` (just follow the left branch all the way down), so it seems odd that this would help at all. Can you comment on why it would?

Comment: I note that you actually made *two* changes in your final code block: one was adding an `SNat` argument, either implicitly via a `KnownNat` constraint or explicitly as an argument, and the other was leaving off the existing `Applicative` constraint. The latter is enough; per my previous comment, the former seems to be a complete red herring.